# How to automatically rollback a transaction?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

How to automatically roll back every transaction after, for example, 10 seconds?

Does this parameter do the job?
`idle_in_transaction_session_timeout`

It looks good, but it kills only idle sessions. Is it ok to kill also active transactions, if they are too long? If yes, how should I do this?

The context is to avoid deadlocks, stop overloadings, bring stability, etc. Of course, this is the "last chance" securitization of the DB. It does not replace all good practices like watching the query plans, designing indexes, constraints and transaction content, etc...

Edit: Global automatic transaction rollback is not a good idea. I plan to insert a timeout application side for long migration transactions inside the client itself.

Comment: " stop overloadings"  Queries are submitted for a reason.  Killing the query generally doesn't remove the reason.  So someone is probably just going to submit the query again, leading to even more load, not decreased load.

Comment: In this particular case it is transaction started by migration work and they can reveal too heavy. Even testing on dumps do not reveal that because staging databases are not under load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it ok to kill also active transactions, if they are too long?

That the transaction is running for a long time is only a *Symptom*, not the root cause of the real *Problem*.  It would be far better to find out ***why*** the transactions are taking so long and fix *that*.
Also, it will very, very annoying for your Users if *their work* is "randomly" killed off by "the computer" - expect *lots* of complaints.

An analogy: How would you "feel" if MS Word (or whichever word-processor you use) randomly shut itself down (*without* auto-saving your changes)?  You'd get very annoyed with it very, *very* quickly.

> The context is to avoid deadlocks, stop overloadings, bring stability, etc.

- "Deadlocks": *Totally* different beasts.
  It's when one Transaction updates A then wants to update B and another Transaction has updated B and now wants to update A.  Both Transactions would wait *forever* for the other to finish, so the DBMS picks one and kills it off.
  There is [often] *nothing* that the database can do about it - it [usually] requires application code changes to resolve it.
- "Overloading":
  Killing off Transactions might actually make things *worse* because, when you kill a Transaction, everything that it's done up to that point has to be *rolled back* and, quite often, that will take priority over *everything else* that the database is trying to do.  (I once had to kill an Oracle Transaction that had been running for over eight hours - the entire database locked up *solid* for 20 minutes while the rollback was happening).
- "Stability":
  Seriously?  Changes being "randomly" killed off and Users having to redo work, the whole database running slowly because of the "random" rollbacks that are happening ...
  Would *you* call that "stable"?

> ... this is the "last chance" securitization of the DB.

IMHO, this is *not* a realistic, long-term proposition to "secure" your database.

Find and fix the *real* problem.

Comment: Note that a rollback in Postgres is **way** cheaper than in Oracle due to the completely different MVCC implementation

Comment: Agreed!  Just about /everything/ is cheaper in Postgres than in Oracle!  
Presumably you still wind up with bloated data files, though, filled with the created and then "discarded" row versions?

Comment: Thank you, Phill. I was maybe too quick with the last part of my question.
I do know that very long work in my app is always a failing work and it will save resources to kill it, and I would like to know how. Be sure that real problems' origins are also tracked as a first important goal ;)

Comment: @Slim "*I do know that very long work in my app is always a failing work and it will save resources to kill it*" - It may logically save some resources, but as Phil mentioned, rolling back a transaction can potentially be time consuming, require more work than committing it, and even fall victim to or create locking issues (depending on isolation level) which will result in more work on your database in actuality than you realize. Rolling back transactions are not simple and immediate things. As Phil mentioned, its better off correcting the root issue which in this case can be your app design.

Comment: OK J. D. thank you for pointing that. If the transaction still have 1000h of remaining work, maybe it's good to rollback it instead of letting it continue, it depends of the work. In this case, the transaction i want to kill is  bad technical refactorings, because it's possible we do not detect it before it's in prod, because the staging has no load. Do you face this kind of problem? I perfectly understand it's not a way to heal things, it's just to stop this too heavy refactor.

Comment: Rolling back a Transaction that still has lots of "work" to do just means that the Transaction is going to get run /again/, some time later, because that "work" still has to happen!  
Anything Database-Transactional that takes more than a few /seconds/ should be reported as a Defect. 
I would suggest that your [company's] /real/ problem is insufficient or inadequate Application testing!  This is what Non-Functional (or Load) Testing environments are specifically for - testing the Application with a load that is *representative* of Live.

Answer (score 0):

So the whole migration will abort and not automatically retry, and then you try it again during off hours or after investigating the problem?  I'm not really sold it on it being a good idea, but it is certainly more plausible to do this in a migration than doing this as a global setting.

statement_timeout is the setting you would want.  Once a statement times out, it throws an error the entire transaction will roll back automatically.  It might make more sense to timeout the entire migration, not each individual step. But I don't think there is any setting to do that.  If the migration is a shell script, maybe you could arrange for the shell to handle cancelation.

Comment: Not exactly. The migration is planned to run at night to have reduced activity. But I am not able to know if it will be really ok. (it's ok in staging but there is no traffic at all on staging) 
Something taking 12 minutes can take 30 minutes or 100hr... no predictable at all.
I would like to have something able to say: "ok kill this migration because it takes too much. Rollback it and the dev will work again". 
I agree it's like testing I prod but we have so many things to do, and sometimes
Our system is far from perfect, but we need big migrations to enhance it.